# Populating string in an array of pointers to structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm reviewing pointers in C and am creating some practice exercises for myself.  I thought it would be good to read in some structs via an array of struct pointers, then display and sort the array.  The problem I'm having is, I feel, rather basic.  The below code reads in the first entry, however the firstName string is always null.  After printing the first struct and continuing the second it goes 'boom' at the time to read into the firstName string.  I thought I initialized the char strings correctly in initParty(), so I'm not sure what the problem is here.  Any ideas?

Sample run:

*(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/remnux/C/struct 
Enter the firstname: john 
Enter the lastname: smith
Enter the ssn: 1234
(null) smith, 1234

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004009a4 in getParty (p=0x0) at struct.c:51
51    scanf("%s", p->firstName);
(gdb)*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct person{
    char *firstName;
    char *lastName;
    int ssn;
  };  

void print(struct person* p){ 
  printf("\n%s ", p->firstName);
  printf("%s, ", p->lastName);
  printf("%d\n ", p->ssn);
}

bool isGreaterThan(struct person *p1, struct person *p2){
  return (strcmp(p1->firstName > p2->firstName) > 0)
    || ((strcmp(p1->firstName > p2->firstName) ==  0) && (strcmp(p1->lastName > p2->lastName) > 0)) 
    || ((strcmp(p1->firstName > p2->firstName) ==  0) && (strcmp(p1->lastName > p2->lastName) == 0)) && (p1->ssn - p2->ssn > 0); 
}

void printArray(struct person** parray, int size){
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%s %s, %d", parray[i]->firstName, parray[i]->lastName, parray[i]->ssn);
}

void sort(struct person** parray, int size){
  int i, j;
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < size-1; j++){
      if(isGreaterThan(parray[j], parray[j+1])){
        struct person *temp = parray[j];
        parray[j] = parray[j+1];
        parray[j+1] = temp;
      }   
    }    
return;
}

void initParty(struct person *p){
    p = (struct person*)malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    p->firstName = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    p->lastName = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
}

void getParty(struct person *p){
  int ch;
  printf("\nEnter the firstname: ");
  scanf("%s", p->firstName);
  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
  printf("\nEnter the lastname: ");
  scanf("%s", p->lastName);
  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
  printf("\nEnter the ssn: ");
  scanf("%d", &(p->ssn));
  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
}

int main(){
  int i, ch, size = 2;
//  printf("Input the number of people you wish to enter: ");
//  scanf("%d", &size);
//  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
  struct person *parray[size];
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
    initParty(parray[i]);
    getParty(parray[i]);
    print(parray[i]);
  }
  sort(parray, size);
  printArray(parray, size);
}
```

***Edit, after eliminating the warnings when compiling with -Wall:***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct person{
    char *firstName;
    char *lastName;
    int ssn;
  };  

void print(struct person* p){ 
  printf("\n%s ", p->firstName);
  printf("%s, ", p->lastName);
  printf("%d\n ", p->ssn);
}

/*bool isGreaterThan(struct person *p1, struct person *p2){
  return ((strcmp(p1->firstName > p2->firstName) > 0)
    || ((strcmp(p1->firstName > p2->firstName) ==  0) && (strcmp(p1->lastName > p2->lastName) > 0))
    || ((strcmp(p1->firstName > p2->firstName) ==  0) && (strcmp(p1->lastName > p2->lastName) == 0) && (p1->ssn - p2->ssn > 0))); 
}*/

void printArray(struct person** parray, int size){
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%s %s, %d", parray[i]->firstName, parray[i]->lastName, parray[i]->ssn);
}

/*void sort(struct person** parray, int size){
  int i, j;
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < size-1; j++){
      if(isGreaterThan(parray[j], parray[j+1])){
        struct person *temp = parray[j];
        parray[j] = parray[j+1];
        parray[j+1] = temp;
      }
 }    
  return;
} */

void initParty(struct person *p){
    p = (struct person*)malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    p->firstName = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    p->lastName = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
}

void getParty(struct person *p){
  int ch;
  printf("\nEnter the firstname: ");
  scanf("%s", p->firstName);
  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
  printf("\nEnter the lastname: ");
  scanf("%s", p->lastName);
  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
  printf("\nEnter the ssn: ");
  scanf("%d", &(p->ssn));
  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
}

int main(){
  int i, size = 2;
//  printf("Input the number of people you wish to enter: ");
//  scanf("%d", &size);
//  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
  struct person *parray[size];
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
    initParty(parray[i]);
    getParty(parray[i]);
    print(parray[i]);
  }
  //sort(parray, size);
  printArray(parray, size);
  return 0;
 }    
  return;
} */

void initParty(struct person *p){
    p = (struct person*)malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    p->firstName = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    p->lastName = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
}

void getParty(struct person *p){
  int ch;
  printf("\nEnter the firstname: ");
  scanf("%s", p->firstName);
  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
  printf("\nEnter the lastname: ");
  scanf("%s", p->lastName);
  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
  printf("\nEnter the ssn: ");
  scanf("%d", &(p->ssn));
  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
}

int main(){
  int i, size = 2;
//  printf("Input the number of people you wish to enter: ");
//  scanf("%d", &size);
//  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
  struct person *parray[size];
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
    initParty(parray[i]);
    getParty(parray[i]);
    print(parray[i]);
  }
  //sort(parray, size);
  printArray(parray, size);
  return 0;
 }    
  return;
} */

void initParty(struct person *p){
    p = (struct person*)malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    p->firstName = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    p->lastName = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
}

void getParty(struct person *p){
  int ch;
  printf("\nEnter the firstname: ");
  scanf("%s", p->firstName);
  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
  printf("\nEnter the lastname: ");
  scanf("%s", p->lastName);
  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
  printf("\nEnter the ssn: ");
  scanf("%d", &(p->ssn));
  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
}

int main(){
  int i, size = 2;
//  printf("Input the number of people you wish to enter: ");
//  scanf("%d", &size);
//  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
  struct person *parray[size];
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
    initParty(parray[i]);
    getParty(parray[i]);
    print(parray[i]);
  }
  //sort(parray, size);
  printArray(parray, size);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: `6.5.2.2 Function calls, 4 An argument may be an expression of any complete object type. In preparing for the call
to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument. 93) A function may change the values of its parameters, but these changes cannot affect the values of the
arguments.`. C is call-by-value.

Comment: Your `printArray()` code should, as a matter of policy, be calling your `print()` function — though it might be better to rename that to `printPerson()`.

Comment: There are a fair number of critical compiler warnings and errors to be fixed. For example, your use of `strcmp()` is completely wrong, and you've not included the relevant header `<string.h>`.

Comment: Your `initParty()` function is setting its local copy of the pointer; it is not changing the element of the array in `main()`.  You need to pass a pointer to the pointer to a structure and modify the called function accordingly.

Comment: `strcmp(a>b)` ? This doesn't do what you expect, but the quirkiness lets you write that and even compiles. And, oh yes, the program crashes hard. Correct is `strcmp(a,b)`

Comment: @EOF: you're right, I see this now that I compile with -Wall.  Sheesh, my bad, those were some glaring problems with the sorting portion.  The problem still remains, but this is a good reminder.  I've fixed and commented the offending code, will edit in a sec.

Comment: @patricio2626: It seems something went wrong with your "fixed code". Duplicate `main()` is not something the compiler likes to see.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, changing initParty's signature to (struct person**p and dereferencing p did the trick, along with a change of the initParty call to (&(parray[i])).  Your explanation makes sense, and seems to be what EOF was saying.

Comment: What I still don't understand is:  parray[i] is a pointer to a struct.  I thought (incorrectly) that this would allow me to modify the underlying struct being pointed to in initParty().  Sorry if I'm being dense here, but why exactly did I have to pass what seems to be (more or less) a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: I agree that EOF was identifying the same problem in a somewhat less easily understood form.  Always compile with `-Wall` (I use `-Wall -Wextra W-error -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wold-style-declaration` (with the prototype stuff being partly anal-retentiveness, partly working on an old code base with (still) some K&R function definitions — and people who don't recognize that `SomeType *function();` is _not_ a prototype, just a declaration without type information for the parameter list) — and sometimes more options (e.g. `-Wshadow` or `-Wnested-externs`).

Comment: I have to say, ladies/gentlemen, these downvotes serve to discourage use of the forum.  Those of us who ask questions do so because we are stuck.  The answer may be simple, however, it can be difficult finding situations that *appear* to be identical in forums, as they can be hidden in the 'syntactic sugar' differences and different ways of expressing the same construct.

Comment: You must pass a pointer to a pointer so that the pointer in the calling code can be changed.  When you pass `parray[i]`, the calling function gets a copy of the current value of `parray[i]`.  In your function as originally written, you overwrite the value passed into the function with the memory allocation, but that's only affecting the function's copy of the pointer — not the pointer in the array in the calling code.  It's an endless source of problems.  An alternative design calls `parray[i] = initParty();` and uses `struct person *initParty(void) { struct person *p = …; return p; }`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler okay, so if I wish to modify anything at all inside a function I need to reference it in the call, then dereference in the called function in order for the modification to affect the original.  I didn't know that this also applied to pointers themselves (and pointers to pointers, and so forth.)

Comment: @patricio2626: Good questions are useful to a larger audience. You ask us to debug your code, basically. This is not likely to be useful to anyone else but you. I guess this is why this question has been downvoted.

Comment: @ammoQ Okay, then I have to respond by saying that I was unaware that this was not a place to ask for help if not a generally helpful question.  When does one decide whether a question is generally helpful or not?  I suppose I can pay a tutor to answer questions that I run into, as that is not a problem.

Comment: @patricio2626: Actually you got several helpful comments, so you shouldn't be too disappointed. Some users downvote questions like yours and other users try to help. That's to be expected here.

Comment: @ammoQ You're right, of course, and my program now works 100%, including the sort portion.  I suppose I'll be more careful in the future when submitting questions, but I still have no idea how I am supposed to distinguish between a helpful and non-helpful question.  I am no stranger to programming, but I am to the concept of explicit pointers.  We all have to start somewhere.

Comment: @patricio2626: There have been months, if not years, of discussion on meta about what kind of questions are welcome here, and the cleanup that followed alienated many users. I recommend that you try harder to pinpoint the bug in your program, so you can e.g. ask `why does strcmp("a">"b") crash?` instead of posting dozens of lines of code next time.

Comment: @ammoQ strcmp wasn't even on my radar :-)  Okay, next time I'll post a 'barebones' program that shows the crux of the problem.  This does make sense.

Comment: @patricio2626: Do that. For your reading pleasure: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Since the contributions have all been comments and not answers I suppose I'll answer this myself. The problem is that I was passing the pointer to the struct to the function, and hence the structure was modifying the local pointer copy since C is pass-by-value.  If one wishes to modify the object pointed to then the pointer must be referenced, so that the main object can be modified when deferenced inside the function.  The following changes did the trick:

```
void initParty(struct person **p){
    *p = (struct person*)malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    (*p)->firstName = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    (*p)->lastName = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
}
```

And the call:

```
  initParty(&(parray[i]));
```

Comment: Note that `initParty(&parray[i]);` is equivalent to what you wrote; the inner parentheses are not necessary or conventional, though they are otherwise harmless.